# Trying to improve choppy ipad screen capture

Tags: video, video-quality, conversion

I'm trying to improve the choppy screen capture that I'm getting on my ipad.

The screen capture plays smoothly when viewed on the ipad itself, however it is choppy when played on my pc in vlc, and even worse when played in filmora. I have tried the native screen recording function in iOS and third party screen recording software apps, some noticeably better than others.

Converting the file in handbrake improves it quite a bit, and I have experimented with various frame rates such as constant frame rate, 29.97, 60, etc, but the choppiness is still noticeable, and the speed is different than the original, and the still space between motion is truncated.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When your recording plays smoothly on one device, then the recording is unlikely to be the issue. What are the specs of your pc? Make sure that you have a powerful cpu and gpu as well as enough ram. Also, what container is the file in? Is it a quicktime (.mov) file? (at least I assume so given that you're using an ipad). If so, try loading up the footage with in the quicktime player instead of vlc. Also, try using premiere or a similar program that allows you to switch through resolutions for your preview (you can select an 8th of the original quality and see if it plays smoothly).

Once again though, when your file plays smoothly somewhere, but causes problems on your pc, it might be an issue with codecs (which I doubt since you got it to play) or with the periphery. Nothing wrong with the video though.